# Measuring RTT with visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, tcp, roundtrip

I am trying to measure RTT with visual studio.
Now, when I call the function:

```
GetTcpRow(554, clientPort, MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB,(PMIB_TCPROW) serverConnectRow);
if (winStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf
        (L"\nGetTcpRow failed on the server established connection with %d",
         winStatus);
    goto bail;
```

it returns the value 1168 to the variable `winStatus`
and then prints the message `nGetTcpRow failed on the server established connection with 1168` and stops running.

Does anyone know what the problem is? What does the function `GetTcpRow` do?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you do not try to write multi-language source files. Writing plain C or C++ is already hard enough: you don't need to deal with the issues of making source code compatible with both languages.

Comment: "visual studio" isn't a language it is an IDE, please amend the question.  Are you just copying from an [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485735(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: When C++ people hear rtt some think RunTime Type (Information) instead of Round Trip Time.

Comment: yes, i ment round trip time... sorry for the confusion..

Comment: i tried to take a working code from studants from last year and make it work. it is a continual project..

Answer (score 0):

Google found the code for GetTcpRow() here

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485735(v=vs.85).aspx
```

There are multiple error legs in the code.  You need to lookup the values of
the various return codes to see which error leg is happening.